# Hide/replace when typing a Password (C#)

Tags: c#, passwords

Ok, So I am new to C#, but already learned a bit. But I have one question, how do I Replace Characters that are typed into a console with "*" or just hide them completely?

```
        var pw = "eric123";
        Console.WriteLine("Password: ");
        var value = Console.ReadLine();
        if (value == pw)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Permitted, Play online? (Y/N)?");
            var getGameOnlineStatus = Console.ReadLine();

            //Rest Of the Code is just for me :)
```

Any Help would be appreciated!

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/thread/32102/password-in-C-Sharp-console-application.aspx

Answer (score 23):

found it [here](http://rajeshbailwal.blogspot.com/2012/03/password-in-c-console-application.html)

Password masking in C# console application

```
class PasswordExample
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Pls key in your Login ID");
            var loginid = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Pls key in your Password");
            var password = ReadPassword();
            Console.Write("Your Password is:" + password);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }


     public static string ReadPassword()
        {
            string password = "";
            ConsoleKeyInfo info = Console.ReadKey(true);
            while (info.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter)
            {
                if (info.Key != ConsoleKey.Backspace)
                {
                    Console.Write("*");
                    password += info.KeyChar;
                }
                else if (info.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
                    {
                        // remove one character from the list of password characters
                        password = password.Substring(0, password.Length - 1);
                        // get the location of the cursor
                        int pos = Console.CursorLeft;
                        // move the cursor to the left by one character
                        Console.SetCursorPosition(pos - 1, Console.CursorTop);
                        // replace it with space
                        Console.Write(" ");
                        // move the cursor to the left by one character again
                        Console.SetCursorPosition(pos - 1, Console.CursorTop);
                    }
                }
                info = Console.ReadKey(true);
            }
            // add a new line because user pressed enter at the end of their password
            Console.WriteLine();
            return password;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static string HideCharacter()
    {
        ConsoleKeyInfo key;
        string code = "";
        do
        {
            key = Console.ReadKey(true);

            if (Char.IsNumber(key.KeyChar))
            {
                    Console.Write("*");
            }
            code += key.KeyChar;
        } while (key.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter);

        return code;

    }
```

`password = HideCharacter();`

Answer (score 0):

```cs
using System;

class Login{

  static void Main() {

    string passwd = HideCharacter();
    Console.WriteLine(passwd);

  }

   public static string HideCharacter()

    {
        ConsoleKeyInfo key;
        string code = "";
        do
        {
            key = Console.ReadKey(true);
            if (Char.IsNumber(key.KeyChar)||Char.IsLetter(key.KeyChar))
            {
                    Console.Write("*");
                    code += key.KeyChar;
            }
        } while (key.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter);
        return code;
    }
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?